# How to upload Child page to Confluence using REST Api/JSON object with python?

Tags: python, json, git, rest, confluence

I want to create a program that uploads the changes in our git repo periodically to confluence.
So far i have these:
- the program collects the changes from the git repository
- formats it according to a pre-defined html template and saves it to a text file
- later it is parsed with python into a JSON object

The problem is that i haven't worked with rest api before, and i don't know how to use it to upload the changes as a child page to an existing page in confluence.
I have searched a lot, but i haven't found any solution that fits my need, or just i can not understand them due to lack of knowledge in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Confluences REST API Documentation is available [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#d3e1426):

as per the document you need to update, the following uri to perform your request will be necessary:

```
/rest/api/content/{contentId}
```

If you have never done API requests using python, there are several libraries available depending on what version of python you are using. [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), [Http.client](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/http.client.html), [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) 1,2,3 etc etc..

to perform a simple authenticated request, you will most likely be needing a token provided by confluence or admin credentials:

Examples of Requests can be found at [developers.atlassian.com](https://developer.atlassian.com/confcloud/confluence-rest-api-examples-39985294.html)
Add a comment to a page:

```
import requests, json

def printResponse(r):
    print '{} {}\n'.format(json.dumps(r.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')), r)

r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content',
    params={'title' : 'Page title to comment on'},
    auth=('admin', 'admin'))

printResponse(r)

parentPage = r.json()['results'][0]

pageData = {'type':'comment', 'container':parentPage,
    'body':{'storage':{'value':"<p>A new comment</p>",'representation':'storage'}}}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content',
    data=json.dumps(pageData),
    auth=('admin','admin'),
    headers=({'Content-Type':'application/json'}))

printResponse(r)
```

Comment: The problem that, i want to upload a child page to an existing page, not updating its content. Also i am using python 2.7. If i create the child page in one step and update it in another step, this solution that you wrote is good for me. But i wanted to do it in one step. Also the developers.atlassian.com link is broken.

Comment: i have updated the link, so. you need to Upload an attachment?

Comment: No, I have to create a new page, but under an existing page.